# How should I detect which request is loaded by which script?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

In order to analyze the third party scripts on our site I'd like to create an overview of all the requests and cluster them. During my research I figured out that there is a [PerformanceObserver Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver). This seems to be already quite useful. For example you can get an overview over the pages requests in JSON format with:

```
performance
        .getEntries()
        .map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry, null, 2))
        .forEach(json => console.log(json));
```

(Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/performance-timeline-2/)

Unfortunately there is no info about the request's referrer. For example I want to know if the origin's URL requested something or if an ad script requested an additional script. Is there a way to get this information somehow?

When using the performance tool Speedcurve which is based on webpagetest.org and clicking on a request there is this information available under "loaded by". I don't know if there is also a Web API or some JavaScript code for this. I wasn't able to find anything yet.

Comment: Hm, well, this info is available in the "Initiator" column of Chrome's dev tools Network tab. I'm unaware of any way to get that info programmatically though.

Comment: Interesting question, but I imagine that what you are after might have some pretty significant security ramifications (especially when dealing with [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)), so my gut feeling is that the solutions you'll find are going to be pretty limited from within JavaScript. Likely you'll end up needing control over the browser itself (e.g. [headless chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) instances)